# Send a GET request with a body in JavaScript (XMLHttpRequest)

Tags: javascript, ajax, rest, xmlhttprequest, http-get

I have to interact with an API that takes parameters from the body of a GET request. I know this might not be the best idea, but it is the way the API was built.

When I try building a query with `XMLHttpRequest`, it looks like the payload is simply not sent. You can run this and look in the network tab; the request is sent, but there is no body (tested in latest Chrome and Firefox):

```js
const data = {
  foo: {
    bar: [1, 2, 3]
  }
}
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
xhr.open('GET', 'https://my-json-server.typicode.com/typicode/demo/posts')
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8')
xhr.send(JSON.stringify(data))
```

Libraries such as axios are built on XMLHttpRequest, so they are not working either...

Is there any way to achieve this in JavaScript?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

No, it is not possible to send a GET request with a body in JavaScript.

> it looks like the payload is simply not sent

That is correct. This is defined in [the specification](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#the-send()-method):

> The `send(body)` method must run these steps:
>
> ...
>
> 3. If the request method is `GET` or `HEAD`, set *body* to null.

Also a request via the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) does not allow a body. From [the specification](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-request):

> 34. If either init["body"] exists and is non-null or inputBody is non-null, and request’s method is `GET` or `HEAD`, then throw a TypeError.

The best would be if the API could be fixed.

If that is not possible, you could add a server-side script that you can use as a proxy that passes the requests to the API. You can than call this script with a GET request with the data in the URL instead of the body or using a POST request with a body. This script then can make the GET request with a body (as long as the chosen language supports it).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. A server-side proxy is a great suggestion.

Comment: Not to anger the HTTP gods but, for the record, in 2019, this spec seems dumb.

I often find myself wanting to send some payload along with a request. It's possible that the payload is very large so I don't want it to be in the URL.

Semantically, I'm conducting a GET request ("Give me something. Here are details of what I want. Don't create anything.") and this spec requires me to make it a POST/PUT request or use some other hackery.

Comment: @JohnCarrell The HTTP spec actually does not forbid it: "A payload within a GET request message has no defined semantics; sending a payload body on a GET request might cause some existing implementations to reject the request."
https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-4.3.1

Comment: @Sergey It has (AFAIK) always been _allowed_ but in earlier versions of the specs [it "_SHOULD_" be ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/a/983458/479156).

Comment: I have argued that these frameworks are broken for over a decade.  REST > HTTP.  If I want to Represent that I want to GET some data given certain parameters, and those parameters are either not appropriate for a Querystring either because of serialization simplicity, size, charset, security, or any other reason, I should be able to pass those parameters with a Body to a `GET` endpoint.  It is not RESTfully correct to request data (even if based on parameters) by calling `PUT` or `POST`. (Not that you can't expect those to return data after their respective add/update action(s)).

Comment: `The best would be if the API could be fixed.` - The API isn't broken.  The frameworks consuming it are.

Comment: The trouble using the body of a GET request to describe a query is that, for historical reasons, the body is not considered by caches.

A GET request describing a query then "poisons" any caches the request flowed through such that subsequent GET attempts, with a different body, will return the original result. The observed behaviour of the API then becomes dependent on the network topology.

It's a defect waiting in the wings.

Comment: Compare to a POST, which cannot be cached, made to a /query endpoint that "creates" a new query. Best practice might be to return a new address and require a GET, but many APIs will just return the result in anticipation.